# Remove Event Listener , arrow function

Tags: javascript

i want to ask you, how to remove an event listener with arrwo functions ? I tried  some methods here but not worked
Any Solution ?

```js
add.addEventListener("click" , ()=> {
  let b = document.createElement("input");
  b.setAttribute("id" , "dif");
  b.type = "number";
  b.placeholder = "Write Third Number";
  calc.append(b);
  
})

add.removeEventListener("click" );
```

Comment: `removeEventListener` requires a reference of the function to remove. You'll have to keep a reference of that arrow function (e.g. put it in a variable, or an object) and use that reference later during removal.

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove you would need a reference to the callback you gave for the add, so you would need to declare the function outside and give it to the add event listener and then remove it:

```
let myClick = ()=> {
  let b = document.createElement("input");
  b.setAttribute("id" , "dif");
  b.type = "number";
  b.placeholder = "Write Third Number";
  calc.append(b); 
};

add.addEventListener("click" , myClick ):

add.removeEventListener("click", myClick );
```

Comment: nice solution but now  not worked to create an input from the button ,,,, i want to create one input and no more any other inputs

Comment: This creates an input every click.. if you want just one create it outside the click, say where you create the button and append it to calc. and then use `document.getElementById("dif")` to find it in the document.. If you do that you can set attribute, type and placeholder in the myClick function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `removeEventListener`, you need to use a named function when adding.

```
function listener () {
  let b = document.createElement("input");
  b.setAttribute("id" , "dif");
  b.type = "number";
  b.placeholder = "Write Third Number";
  calc.append(b);
}
add.addEventListener("click", listener);
...
add.removeEventListener("click", listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because `removeEventListener` requires that you pass as argument both the type of event (e.g. click) and the event listener function to be removed (the arrow function).

The reason you must provide both is because you could attach multiple event listeners for the same event for the same event.

To make it work, you have two solutions:

1. Extract the arrow function to a named function. For example:

```
function doSomethingOnClick() {
// Do some stuff
}

element.addEventListener('click', doSomethingOnClick);

// later ...

element.removeEventListener('click', doSomethingOnClick);
```

2. Assign your arrow function to a variable. For example:

```
const doSomethingOnClick = () => console.log('Doing some stuff ...');

element.addEventListener('click', doSomethingOnClick);

// later ...

element.removeEventListener('click', doSomethingOnClick);
```

For more information, have a look at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)